# Find probability from $\gcd$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we are given a set $X=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ and suppose $M_1$, $M_2$, $\ldots$, $M_k$ are subsets of $X$. Then the probability that there exists one number in $X$ let say $a$ which satisfied $\gcd(a,\gcd(M_k))=1$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is $1$ because $1 \in X$ and $\gcd(1,\text{anything})=1$ so take $a=1$